# Up close and personal equivalent

Tags: vocabulary, idioms, sentence

How do you express something similar to “up close and personal”?

Like this sentence: She likes to get up close and personal.

Comment: “Up close and personal” could mean a few different things. It may help if you elaborate on *exactly* what it is that you are trying to express here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the context and the desired nuance, there can be different translations for this expression. I shall follow the main definitions given by [Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/up+close+and+personal):

**1. *adjective* Very physically close to someone or something. Hyphenated if used before a noun.**

> 蘇菲亞告訴我，她會在我們的衝浪之行中當我的私人教練。我喜歡這個主意，因為這就表示我們可以**有近距離的接觸**。
>
> Sofia has told me she would be my personal instructor on our surfing excursion. I like that because it means we will be getting *up close and personal* with each other.

The above example is from [here](https://tw.appledaily.com/international/20090911/VT2HPSBXOUQGVZTD6LOVDGDHXU/). 有近距離的接觸 (*lit.* to have contact in close distance) is a rather neutral saying. Other slightly more intimate adjectives that can be added before 接觸, with or without 的, include 親密 and 密切. Alternatively, the verb 親近 can be used if a specific object is identified, as in

> 她喜歡親近你。
>
> She likes to be close to you.

**2. *adjective* Very intimate and personal, especially to an uncomfortable or unwanted degree. Hyphenated if used before a noun.**

> 我不喜歡男人在最初數次的約會上便**跟我套近乎**。
>
> I don't like it when guys try to get too *up close and personal* in our first couple of dates.

套近乎 has a derogatory meaning and is rather colloquial. [Here](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E5%A5%97%E8%BF%91%E4%B9%8E) provides the definition 'to worm one's way into being friends with someone'. Usually there is an ulterior purpose implied.

**3. *adverb* In a very close and intimate manner or to such a degree.**

> 那些審計師對於我們的財務習慣**瞭如指掌**。
>
> The auditors got to know our financial habits very *up close and personal*.

This specific sense is best translated as the idiom 瞭如指掌 (*lit.* knowing something as clear as pointing that on one's palm to others).

---

I would say the given sentence can be translated as 她喜歡與人有親密接觸 or 她喜歡跟別人套近乎. There may be better translations than these.

Comment: The last two phrases will work in my application.  It has that humor “喜歡”.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean she's a nosey b....

她喜欢窥探别人的隐私。

Comment: Very close to what I was looking for.